# apache2: host multiple sites under same domain in local server

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I've a local server with LAMP, ubuntu and apache2, and want to install several web applications (openproject, vtiger, suitecrm, sugar crm, ...) to test them. All them are web-based services.

I've unpacked them under /var/www and configured the virtual hosts as:

For Vtiger service: */etc/apache2/sites-available/vtigercrm.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin angel@usmima.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/vtigercrm
ServerName vtigercrm
ServerAlias vtigercrm.serverMachine.synology.me 
Alias /vtigercrm /var/www/vtigercrm

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vtigercrm-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vtigercrm-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

For Suite crm service: */etc/apache2/sites-available/suitecrm.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin angel@usmima.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/suitecrm
ServerName suitecrm
ServerAlias suitecrm.serverMachine.synology.me
ServerAlias localhost
Alias /suitecrm /var/www/suitecrm 

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/suitecrm-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/suitecrm-access.log combined

   <Directory /var/www/suitecrm/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And for openproject: */etc/apache2/sites-available/openproject.conf*

```
Include /etc/openproject/addons/apache2/includes/server/*.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName openproject
  ServerAlias serverMachine.synology.me
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot /opt/openproject/public

  ProxyRequests off

  Include /etc/openproject/addons/apache2/includes/vhost/*.conf

  ProxyPass /openproject/ http://127.0.0.1:6000/openproject/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse /openproject/ http://127.0.0.1:6000/openproject/
</VirtualHost>
```

I can access to each one of the services with their ServerAlias addresses:

- vtigercrm.serverMachine.synology.me
- suitecrm.serverMachine.synology.me
- serverMachine.synology.me/openproject

but if I want to access them locally, *http://localhost/openproject* is the only one working. *http://localhost/suitecrm* or *http://localhost/vtigercrm* do not work.

How do I have to configure so I can access to each service as accessing to the different folders of the same domain? For instance:

- http://localhost/suitecrm      or     http://192.168.1.123/suitecrm
- http://localhost/vtigercrm      or     http://192.168.1.123/vtigercrm

The case for openproject is working:

- http://localhost/openproject    or  http://192.168.1.123/openproject

Thanks

**EDIT 1**

I've managed to half solve the problem editing the virtual host configuration for openproject adding:

```
Alias /vtigercrm /var/www/vtigercrm
Alias /suitecrm  /var/www/suitecrm
```

Which seems to indicate that openproject is being launched when accessing. What do I have to do to avoid needing openproject virtual host to properly route access to vtiger, suitecrm and other sites?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest changing your system's hosts file.

In `/etc/hosts`

replace

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

with

```
127.0.0.1 serverMachine.synology.me vtigercrm.serverMachine.synology.me suitecrm.serverMachine.synology.me localhost
```

Now simply type in the same address you would if you were on another system - the browser will send exactly the same information as it would for an external user, so Apache will respond in the same way.